# Permission denied when running python "with open" on code inside docker running under 'Celery' user

Tags: python, docker

I have a Celery worker running on a container under a 'Celery' user.

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
celery         1  0.0  0.0   5860  3484 ?        Ss   Sep02   0:00 bash ./start-celeryworker
celery        29  0.4  0.9 368360 155436 ?       Sl   Sep02   0:39 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery -A src.core.celery_app worker --pool=geve
```

The code was running fine until now, when I added `with open(file_name,'wb')` to the code and know I get a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` and I `don`t know to get it to work.

Comment: Have you checked if the celery user has the right permissions to access the file? If it was created as part of a Dockerfile it may be owned by `root` rather than the `Celery` user.

Comment: The file doesn't exist at first. The idea is to create/open the file, write some data to it and upload it to aws s3 using boto3, than delete it from the container. But maybe the directory is owned by root I can open it there. I will check it. Tks